# How to Create a C++ application for RHEL 6 in Windows7-64bit

Tags: c++, windows-7-x64, rhel6

I was working on Java and Python before.
There was no confusion on selecting the compilers between Windows and Linux.
I am new to C++.

Now, I must create a C++ application for RHEL 6.
My development environment is Eclipse 4.2 with CDT on Windows 7 64 bit.

Kindly suggest me if there is a compiler that can deploy the application in RHEL environment from my windows 7 64bit Operating System (as simple as Java/Python)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By far the easiest solution would be to deploy a Linux VM on your windows machine, install Eclipse CDT on it, and compile with the linux native GCC. [Here is an SO Post about compiling for linux under windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2188709/how-do-i-use-cygwin-to-cross-compile-to-linux-when-i-have-an-application-that-n).

Other than that, you could try to use Cygwin's gcc cross-compiler, but I wouldn't bet on it.